# Highlight roads from GPS while driving and storing

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, openstreetmap

Is there a way for Google Maps (or any other map sofware) to mark a road while driving it following the GPS and then keep that mark across sessions?

I would like to explore an area and all its roads and would be nice to be able to avoid roads that have been already visited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an open source app: GPX Tracker that does the job perfectly